# can someone help me with why my string is not working?

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
// declares variables
int items, time;
double heat, h1, h2, h3, h4;
h1 = 1.00;
h2 = 1.25;
h3 = 1.50;
h4 = 2.00;

  Scanner num  = new Scanner(System.in);

 // asks user to input the amount of items to heat and the amount of time to 
heat the items      
  System.out.println("Select number of items being heated");
  items = num.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Select amount of time in seconds to heat one item");
  time = num.nextInt();

    // gets user to re-enter the amount of items to less than 5  
    while (items > 4)
    {
            System.out.println("warning: more than four items is too hot! 
\nplease enter a number below 5");
        items = num.nextInt();
}
//heating calculations
    switch (items)
    {
case 1:
            heat = h1;
    break;
    case 2:
            heat = h2;
    break;

    case 3:

            heat = h3;
    break;
    case 4:
        heat = h4;
default:
    heat = 1;
        }

        // outputs the total time
        System.out.println("Time: " + time * heat * items + " seconds");

 }
 }
```

any help would be great guys! this is for a school project and it says "heat" is not being initialized

Comment: What's your question? What isn't working and what is the expected result?

Comment: i need to use a switch for my code and it tells me that in the final line of code "heat" is not being initialized

Comment: Could it be that the second line of your comment `// asks user to input the amount of items to heat and the amount of time to heat the items ` isn't a comment and, in fact, the line that starts with: `heat the items` is being processed as code?

Comment: I think the `heat the item` is uncommented which is an issue

Comment: You're also missing a `break` after your `case 4` switch statement. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix 3 lines in your code:

1.You forgot to comment heat the items
 //heat the items

2. You forgot to put quotation mark after hot!"
3. you forgot to put addition sign and quotation mark before the word please. U need addition sign in order to write a String in two lines:

System.out.println(" warning: more than four items is too hot! "

```
                + "\nplease enter a number below 5");
```